Issue with signal generation with soldered header
I am learning to solder and have put together a little test program to get started:
It simply waits for the user to push a button, and then sets the 'sda' register to high.
Here is the code:
control.v:
`include "clk_div.v"

module control
(
    input   clk,        // system clock
    input   bbutton,    // button
    output  sda,        // serial data
    output  sck         // serial clock
);
    reg start = 0;
    reg sda_reg;
    wire clk_wire, sck_wire;
    assign sda = sda_reg;
    assign sck = sck_wire;

    initial begin
        start   <= 0;
        sda_reg <= 0;
    end

    always @(posedge sck) begin
        if (bbutton == 0) begin
            start <= 1;
        end

        if (start == 1) begin
            sda_reg <= 1;
        end
    end

    clk_div clk_div (
        .clk(clk),
        .sck(sck_wire)
    );

endmodule

clock_div.v:
`ifndef clk_div_V   // Check if clk_div_V is not defined
`define clk_div_V   // Define clk_div_V

module clk_div(
    input  clk, // Input clock: 27 MHz
    output sck  // Output clock: 3 MHz
);

    // Counter to divide the clock
    reg [3:0] counter; // 4-bit counter (0 to 8 requires at least 4 bits)
    reg sck_reg;
    assign sck = sck_reg;

    initial begin
        counter <= 0;
        sck_reg <= 0;
    end

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (counter == 4'd8) begin
            counter <= 4'b0;        // Reset counter after 8
            sck_reg <= ~sck_reg;    // Toggle output clock
        end else begin
            counter <= counter + 1'b1; // Increment counter
        end
    end

endmodule

`endif

The software testbench looks fine.
On the logic analyzer, when zoomed in - everything looks in order! The serial clock is working as expected, as well as serial data.

The problem is that when zoomed out on sigrok - I am seeing a lot of noise on the sda channel:

As I mentioned, I am learning to solder and so this could be the point of error - the joints in question are number 3/4

Here is how I hooked them up for testing:

Something else that is confusing is that on sigrok the sck channel works ok no matter what pin I route it out on - but the sda seems to always exhibit this behaviour.
I would really appreciate any advice.

connecting the ground pin of the logic ananlyzer module to the ground  of the FPGA module may help


I would really appreciate any advice.

The Verilog code employs 2 clock domains:

System clock
Serial clock

While I don't think this would cause the noise issue you are seeing, this does unnecessarily complicate synthesis because you need to take special care with the timing constraints for the 2 domains.
It would be better to modify the design code to drive all signals off of the single system clock.
From a coding style perspective, the code could be simplified by eliminating the extra assignments like:
assign sck = sck_reg;

The sck signal can be declared as a reg
output reg sck  // Output clock: 3 MHz

Also, the model looks incomplete.  For example, start is set to 0 only at time 0 in simulation (in the initial block).  It is set to 1, but can never be set to 0 again.
